# How to store ArrayList of my class in shared preference?

Tags: java, android

I want to store ArrayList of Polygon objects in shared preference. Can someone help me with this?

To save list:

```
public void savePolygonObjects(Context context){
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(polygonArrayList);
    prefsEditor.putString("myJson", json);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

To retrieve list:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 
                                     getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("myJson", "");
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray array = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonArray();

for(int i=0; i< array.size(); i++){
    polygonArrayList.add(gson.fromJson(array.get(i), Polygon.class));
}
```

Comment: show code that you have tried till now.

Comment: the only way is to convert your array into a JSON string and save it in shared prefs.

Comment: it gives me error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class gs declares multiple JSON fields named d @LucaNicoletti

Comment: Post how you're doing this

Comment: The above code gives me exception saying that cannot convert object to json. it gives error at gson.toJson(list) @LucaNicoletti

Comment: you have to register type adapter in the Gson object, follow the guide [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)

Comment: It is still giving me error at the same line, i guess it is not converting to json for some reason @LucaNicoletti

Comment: Post your updated code

Comment: see i updated @LucaNicoletti, i just want to store ArrayList of Polygons in shared preference, Polygons which are objects of google maps.

Comment: Can you post more code? The class, where you create that `polygonArrayList` and by the way, you're not using Gson to retrieve the data, you use it only to save the data

Comment: I am using gson to retrieve, see inside the for loop @LucaNicoletti, polygonArrayList is just a collection in which i add Polygon objects when a polygon's color is changed

Comment: try this: gson.fromJson(json, Polygon[].class);

Comment: The code does not compile, do you have any other way other than gson and json? @LucaNicoletti

Comment: No, just follow step by step the tutorial I gave, and use the same classes

Comment: Do you have a different example which is a little precise to my subject? @LucaNicoletti

Answer (score 0):

You can add your `ArrayList` as serialized object to the `SharedPreferences` and later deserialize it while reading it from the SharedPreferences.
Here's a code sample for that:

```
ArrayList<Polygon> polygonList = new ArrayList<Polygon>();

// Add the data to the list

// Serializing and adding the ArrayList to the SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  try {
    editor.putString(POLYGONS, ObjectSerializer.serialize(polygonList));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  editor.commit();
```

Then later retrieve the `ArrayList` by deserializing it as follows:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  try {
    polygonList = (ArrayList<POLYGON>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString(POLYGONS, ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<POLYGON>())));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

You need to add the ObjectSerializer class to your project too, you can get it from here: [ObjectSerializer.java](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/89c2e8e76c68d0d0abe6a36b4e08ddc56979796f/src/org/apache/pig/impl/util/ObjectSerializer.java)

I referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057858/6726650), and there is an alternate method too for this so you can check that out too

Comment: which dependencies should i add for org.apache.pig? @Sudhanshu Vohra

Comment: @BhushanBorole copy the class to your project and that will do, Note: remove the dependencies: import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory; and     private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ObjectSerializer.class); as they are not important. Also update the package name too.

Comment: I did all the stuff, but still its not working, there is no exception, but still i am not getting the required data. @Sudhanshu Vohra

Comment: Is that returning "null" when you fetch it from SharedPreferences ?

Comment: Yes @Sudhanshu Vohra

Answer (score -5):

```
List<Person> customer = new ArrayList<Person>();
Person p = .....;
customer.add(person);
```